I am an Australian Citizen on a E3 visa. I have been out of the USA for 4 months working remotely. Will I have issues re entering USA
Been on second E3 visa, still have 1,5 yrs left on it. I have been working remotely in Australia due to my mother been sick. I still work for the company, will I have issues getting back into USA next week.

What did the company you work for say when you asked?

They were not sure.

Why would you have issues?  Has any aspect of your employment changed?
